Backward-compatible SQL query against database with new table
Let's have several Oracle databases and suppose we create table t with columns a, b in some of them.
How to develop an SQL query which can be successfully run against all databases such that

on databases with tables t it behaves as select a, b from t
on databases without table t it returns empty result set with columns a, b.

This is another query in line of seemingly-impossible queries (see here and here). The purpose is to overcome some period in database deployment in which the databases differ. Sanitizing differences in client application is comparably more laborious than temporary - yet sort of hacky - solution.

Why would you do that? What's the use case?

Write a PL/SQL script that does the select with execute immediate and traps exceptions, returning something else when there is no table.

If you can use PL/SQL, conditional compilation would seem like the cleanest way to implement that sort of thing.  Or put branching logic into your PL/SQL that checks all_tables to see if T exists and runs different versions of the query depending.

I am limited by tooling offered by Pentaho Data Integration where Table input block is AFAIK able to process only plain SQL query. Of course I am aware of PL/SQL based solution and use it otherwise. The solution is temporary in the sense that table is spread to all environments within month and also the PDI will be probably replaced in distant future (visual programming is not very comfortable).

The solution is to utilize XML features. Final result set is always recreated from XML. The XML is either built from real data or faked, depending on information about table existence from database catalog.
create table t as select 'a' as a, 'b' as b from dual

with singlexml(xmlcol) as (
  select xmltype(nvl(
           dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from ' || (
             select case count(*) when 0 then 'dual where 0=1' else max(t.table_name) end
             from all_tables t
             where t.table_name = 'T' -- change to X for testing nonexistent table
           ))
           , '<?xml version="1.0"?><ROWSET/>'
         )) 
  from dual
)
select cols.a
     , cols.b
from singlexml
   , xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW'
              passing singlexml.xmlcol
              columns a varchar2(32) path 'A'
                    , b varchar2(32) path 'B'
     ) cols





A
B




a
b



fiddle
